# Testing linking to the receipt using PayPal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been able to create an order, get it approved and capture payment using PayPal sandbox. I would now like to test linking to the receipt for that order.

So, given that the order id assigned by PayPal is `1VC7586169694032B`, based on the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sdk-dev/receipts/) I tried to point my browser to the following locations:

- https://www.paypal.com/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B
- https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B
- https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B
- https://www.api.sandbox.paypal.com/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B
- https://www.api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B
- https://sandbox.paypal.com/v2/receipt/?id=1VC7586169694032B

None of these worked.

So, are receipts for sandbox transactions stored? If so, what is the correct link? If not, how can I test the feature of linking to the order receipt without creating a real live transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An order id is not a PayPal transaction id.  And neither one is a receipt id, much less a PayPal Here invoice id which are the docs and links in your question.

When you capture an order id, the merchant account's transaction id will be in the response at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`.

That id can be looked up in PayPal.com .  Perhaps you could dynamically link to the resulting details page, I haven't tested it.

---

Note that the merchant account and the payer account each have their *own* different transaction id, but it's possible to search for the "other account's" transaction id in paypal.com and still reach the details page.

Comment: I did not see sandbox transactions appear in the dashboard. Do they and where?

Comment: I explored the data returned from the PayPal data upon approval. It has the id `2SM87362YP116414A` exactly where you wrote. However, I still cannot point my browser to view a receipt. So, what is the receipt's location? Note once again that I am testing using sandbox.

Comment: Log into the sandbox seller account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

Comment: I could get to the transaction details page, but I still cannot find a receipt download link that I can give to my client, who may not even have a PayPal account and payed using the black Credit/Debit card button...

Comment: PayPal sends a receipt to them by email. You should just concentrate on being able to show your own order confirmation & status page.

Comment: Typically your system should generate its own "order" or invoice id, which can be passed to PayPal in the invoice_id field at order creation time. And so, you would provide a confirmation/status link on your site that references that ID of yours.  If you need a suggestion about that ID format, try 3 letters that identify your store followed by a dash and some unique number, e.g. ABC-012333434243.   Make sure invoice IDs are unique (never used before for a successful payment on your account)

Comment: The client may request a copy of the receipt and I want to be able to give him a download link to PayPal-generated receipt that does not require logging in to PayPal to download the receipt. If I pass my own invoice ID to PayPal at order creation, what will be the link location for sandbox? Will that link do what I want?

Comment: If they don't have a PayPal account, no. There's nothing you can link them to on PayPal.com .  They'll receive an email notification and that is it.  If you want to link them to a website, it should be your own website.  Preferably with an invoice_id that you generate and which is provided as such at order creation time, so that ID is stored as part of the resulting PayPal transaction.  This is the only way to have an ID in common for reference with both the receiving account and the payer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is the number of seconds since the beginning of epoch a good invoice id? Also, how can I obtain information about the payment method? It does not seem to appear in the response...

Comment: It's more common to use an autonumber that increases with each cart payment attempt.  I'm not sure what information you're looking for about the "payment method" -- PayPal doesn't respond with information about funding sources, and billing information is kept private to the payer by design. That's how PayPal works and the reason people prefer to use it to pay random websites, since all billing information is kept private to PayPal and cannot be compromised

Comment: So, would a number like DM-0000001 be fine to begin with? Things like the name of credit card (e.g. VISA) and the last four digits of the credit card number usually appear on a receipt... Those are the pieces I am looking for, nothing more than that.

Comment: None of that is provided for PayPal payments. You will not know whether the payment was made from a card, or from a bank, or from a PayPal balance, or from PayPal Credit / Pay In 4, or from a number of alternative payment methods available in various countries: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/alternative-payment-methods/ . It is all private to the payer's PayPal account.

Comment: The correct thing to show is simply that the buyer payed with: "PayPal emailofpaypalaccount@domain.com", you do receive the email in the response

Comment: ..but yes a number like that is fine. Just never repeat a number once an order id is successfully captured and results in a transaction, or you will receive a duplicate invoice ID error (to prevent accidental duplicate payments for the same thing). If you have independent integrations they should use a different prefix so as to not clash with each other on the same account.